# Auto save & close workbooks, except VBAWorkbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Currently trying to figure out how to have my code that auto saves and closes open workbooks to avoid vba project workbooks without naming the vba project workbooks. Is there a way to get your code to recognize vba workbooks vs the other open workbooks I'm trying to save and close?

```
Option Explicit
Public ThisFile As String
Public Path As String

Sub CloseAndSaveOpenWorkbooks()
    Dim Wkb As Workbook
    Path = [D1]

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False

        'Loop through the workbooks collection
        For Each Wkb In Workbooks

            With Wkb
            'If NOT on Macro workbook then

                If .Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
                'If the book is read-only
                'don't save but close
                    If Not Wkb.ReadOnly Then
                    'Save current workbook with current workbooks cell A1 as file name
                        .SaveAs Filename:=(Path & "\" & Wkb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value & ".xls"), FileFormat:=xlExcel8

                    End If

                    'Closing here leaves the app running, but no books

                    .Close

                End If

            End With

        Next Wkb

        .ScreenUpdating = True

    End With
End Sub
```

A follow up question to thread: [VBA: Auto save&close out of all current workbooks except for Macro workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169638/vba-auto-saveclose-out-of-all-current-workbooks-except-for-macro-workbook)

Comment: [Here's a question with a lot of helpful answers!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298383/how-to-test-for-existence-of-vba-in-excel-workbook-in-vba)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the link. There wasn't a direct answer, but most definitely had code in there that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer!

Reading through [Article Provided by J_V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298383/how-to-test-for-existence-of-vba-in-excel-workbook-in-vba) most definitely helped. 
I replaced

```
If .Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
```

with

```
If Wkb.HasVBProject = False Then
```

Hope this ends up helping others. Thanks again J_V!

Comment: Glad you found it useful!